# Returning an array of abbreviated NotesNames

Tags: xpages

I've got a configuration document on which I use a single field to store the names of evaluators that are assigned to assess some paperwork. In LotusScript, I was able to message those NotesNames into abbreviated names to build my list without too much wrangling. The array of NotesNames will be used in a combobox to allow users to select the evaluator name.

```
Function getEvaluatorSelections As Variant
    Dim evaluatorArray As Variant
    ReDim evaluatorSelections (0) As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim evalName As NotesName
    count = 0
    evaluatorArray = DetermineMultiValueKeyword ("EVALUATORS")
    ForAll entries In evaluatorArray
        ReDim Preserve evaluatorSelections (count)
        Set evalName = New NotesName ( entries )
        evaluatorSelections (count) = evalName.Abbreviated
        count = count + 1
    End ForAll

    If count = 0 Then
        getEvaluatorSelections = username
    Else
        getEvaluatorSelections = evaluatorSelections
    End If  
End Function
```

When I went to do the same in XPages, I got stymied by starting with a Vector and not really understanding how to write SSJS.

```
var thisdb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var dbProfileView = thisdb.getView("dbprofile");
var evaluatorDoc = dbProfileView.getDocumentByKey("EVALUATORS");
var evaluatorVector:Vector = evaluatorDoc.getItemValue("Value");
return evaluatorVector.toArray();
```

That returns the fully distinguished names, which would be enough for me, but certainly not what the client would like to see.

I tried to put the Vector values into an array and get the abbreviated names, but kept getting Error 500s with variations of the code below:

```
var thisdb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var dbProfileView = thisdb.getView("dbprofile");
var evaluatorDoc = dbProfileView.getDocumentByKey("EVALUATORS");
var evaluatorVector:Vector = evaluatorDoc.getItemValue("Value");
var evaluatorArray = new Array (evaluatorVector.toArray());
var returnArray = new Array(); 
var evalNames:NotesName;

for(var i=1;i<evaluatorArray.length;i++){
    evalNames = New NotesName ( evaluatorArray[i] );
    returnArray[i] = evalNames.getAbbreviated();
}
return returnArray();
```

How do I duplicate what I've in LotusScript over in SSJS? Or have I taken the wrong approach completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had multiple problems.

Pushing the values of the Vector into the array was done improperly. Switch from:

```
var evaluatorArray = new Array (evaluatorVector.toArray());
```

To two lines:

```
var evaluatorArray = new Array ();
evaluatorArray = evaluatorVector.toArray();
```

Then, it should have used session.createName instead of New NotesName. Finally, the return should send the entire array, not some squirrelly returnArray()

```
//get database
var thisdb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
//get view
var dbProfileView = thisdb.getView("dbprofile");
//getDocumentByKey ("EVALUATORS")
var evaluatorDoc = dbProfileView.getDocumentByKey("EVALUATORS");
//getItemValue to get all values from the Value field as a Vector
var evaluatorVector:Vector = evaluatorDoc.getItemValue("Value");
var evaluatorArray = new Array ();
evaluatorArray = evaluatorVector.toArray();
var returnArray = new Array(); 
var evalNames:NotesName;

for(var i=0;i<evaluatorArray.length;i++){
    evalNames = session.createName ( evaluatorArray[i] );
    returnArray[i] = evalNames.getAbbreviated();
}
return returnArray;
```

I'm sure this can be cleaned up and optimized, but it works.

Comment: Just two reminders: recycle evalNames inside "for" loop, and tag your question as answered.

Comment: I have to wait two days to tag it as answered if I answer it myself. Go figure. I'd forgotten about recycling. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: `[]` means the same thing as `new Array()`... same result, less typing each time.

Answer (score 2):

For abbreviating the name you can try this:
var nam:NotesName = session.createName(
    "CN=John B Goode/OU=Sales/OU=East/O=Acme/C=US");
return nam.getAbbreviated();
Which can be found on this wiki document.  http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesName_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages

There are a lot of good docs on that wiki by Robert Perron.

Worse case you can use @Name() in SSJS as well if needed.  I'd try to avoid that though.

What do you want to do with this return array?  What's it going to populate?  Just something on the screen?  A combobox?  etc?

If it's just for display on the screen you can use a repeat control and just repeat each value of the multi-value field.  I kinda like that approach myself... there's other ways to do it though.

I know I'm only answering a piece of the question right now.  Not sure I can do all the rest but need to know what you want to do with the result array first I think.

Comment: Returning it for values in a combobox. Not knowing session.createName was one hurdle. Another was bad handling of the vector to array transition. I'll post the completed code as an answer (then blog about it!)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is a bit old, but I think someone can benefit from the solution. From the question, I guess that you want to return Common Names using SSJS.

One way will be to loop through the list (evaluatorVector) and then convert each names into Common Names before storing the returned values into an array.

Solution below:

```
var evaluatorVector = evaluatorDoc.getItemValue("Value");
var returnArray = []; 
for(var i = 1; i < evaluatorArray.length; i++){
  if(evaluatorVector != null){
      returnArray.push(@Name('[CN]', evaluatorVector[i]));
  }
}
print(returnArray); //list of common names
```